# Django Model MultipleObjectsReturned

Tags: sql-server, django, django-models

I am using django ORM to talk to a SQL Server DB.

I used the .raw() method to run a query:

```
@classmethod
def execute_native_queries(cls, query):
    return cls.objects.raw(query)
```

I later type-cast it into a list by running: `data = list(modelName.execute_native_queries(query))`

While iterating through the list, i would call certain columns as such:

```
for entry in data:
    a = entry.colA
    b = entry.colB
    c = entry.colC
```

For certain entries, I am able to run one loop-iteration fine, however for some i get the following error:

```
api.models.modelName.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one modelName-- it returned 2!
```

What i do not get is how come this error is surfacing?

EDIT: Added the stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<full filepath>\a.py", line 178, in method1
    'vc': data.vc,
  File "C:\FAST\Python\3.6.4\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query_utils.py", line 137, in __get__
    instance.refresh_from_db(fields=[self.field_name])
  File "C:\FAST\Python\3.6.4\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 605, in refresh_from_db
    db_instance = db_instance_qs.get()
  File "C:\FAST\Python\3.6.4\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 403, in get
    (self.model._meta.object_name, num)
api.models.modelName.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one modelName-- it returned 2!
```

Comment: That error is not coming from this code. Show the context and the full traceback.